# Custom canvas drawing code in metro

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

In traditional desktop app, I perform my custom canvas drawing as follow

```
class ChartingView : System.Windows.Controls.Canvas
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        // ... All the juicy drawing code right here.
    }
}
```

However, how about in Metro? As in `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Canvas`, I cannot find `OnRender` method for me to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Children](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) property to populate `Canvas`. You can put there primitives (shapes, lines, etc.) as well as "complex" controls. And as noted in the @Aaron Murgatroyd comment:

> there is no way to just simply draw on a canvas frame by frame

To adjust them on the `Canvas` you should use `Canvas.SetXYZ` methods (see for example [Canvas.SetLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.setleft.aspx) and [Canvas.SetTop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.canvas.settop.aspx) methods).

Comment: A better answer to your question is, no, because "Metro" is based on a graphics pipeline (which is a state based machine) there is no way to just simply draw on a canvas frame by frame (you could maybe use a texture shader). However you can add, remove, and relocate primitives to your hearts content.

Comment: If there is no way to draw on canvas frame by frame, how does a programmer going to implement stuff like basic charting, real-time charting, ...?

Comment: @YanChengCHEOK absence of frame by frame drawing does not mean, that drawing will be slow or impossible.